# Tail recursion with multiple accumulator stages

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion, case-class

I'm trying to determine the best pattern for tail recursion with multiple accumulator stages, judging best by being a balance of efficiency and readability.

The particular scenario is a stream of frames arriving ordered by track and then time. I need to accumulate track information and then accumulate those tracks:

```
case class Frame(trackId: Int, time: Double)
case class Track(id: Int, count: Int, start: Double, end: Double)
```

The pattern I find more readable uses the actual `Track` case class as the track accumulator:

```
def scanTracks(reader: Stream[Frame]): List[Track] = {  
  def scanTracks2(reader2: Stream[Frame], track: Option[Track], acc: List[Track]): List[Track] =
    if (reader2.isEmpty)
      track.map(_ :: acc).getOrElse(acc)
    else {
      val frame = reader2.head
      track match {
        case None => scanTracks2(reader2.tail, Some(Track(frame.trackId,1,frame.time,0)), acc)
        case Some(t) => if(frame.trackId == t.id)
          scanTracks2(
            reader2.tail,
            Some(t.copy(count = t.count+1,end=frame.time)),
            acc
          )
          else
          scanTracks2(
            reader2.tail,
            Some(Track(frame.trackId,1,frame.time,frame.time)),
            t :: acc
          )
      }
    }
  scanTracks2(reader, None, Nil)
}
```

My concern with this pattern is that each recursion does a `copy` of the current track to produce the new track accumulator. While `head::tail` is very efficient, since it's just a cons of an existing list, creating a new copy of `Track` seems less efficient.

The alternative is to explicitly pass all values that will make up a track, so that recursion just changes function parameters:

```
def scanTracks(reader: Stream[Frame]): List[Track] = {  
  def scanTracks2(reader2: Stream[Frame], id: Int, count: Int, start: Double, end: Double, acc: List[Track]): List[Track] =
    if (reader2.isEmpty)
      Track(id, count + 1, start, end) :: acc
    else {
      val frame = reader2.head
      frame.trackId match {
        case -1 => scanTracks2(reader2.tail, frame.trackId, 1, frame.time, 0, acc)
        case x if x == id => scanTracks2(reader2.tail, id, count + 1, start, frame.time, acc)
        case _ =>
          scanTracks2(
            reader2.tail,
            frame.trackId,
            1,
            frame.time,
            0,
            Track(id, count + 1, start, end) :: acc
          )
      }
    }
  scanTracks2(reader, -1, 0, 0, 0, Nil)
}
```

This muddies the function signature and has the *kludge* of using `-1` as a marker of *no track yet*. Overall, I feel that readability has degraded a good bit.

My question is whether my concern about `copy` efficiency is unreasonable in the overall scheme or whether there is yet another pattern for doing this multi-stage accumulation that is better than both of these.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found so far is to have inlined *tail-recursive* functions for additional accumulator stages. Given my example above, I've rewritten as follows:

```
def scanTracks(reader: Stream[Frame]): List[Track] = {

  def scanTracks(scanReader: Stream[Frame], acc: List[Track]): List[Track] =
    if (scanReader.isEmpty)
      acc
    else {
      val frame = scanReader.head

      def scanTrack(trackReader: Stream[Frame], count: Int, end: Double): (Stream[Frame], Track) =
        if (trackReader.isEmpty)
          (trackReader, Track(frame.trackId, count, frame.time, end))
        else {
          val frame2 = trackReader.head
          if (frame2.trackId == frame.trackId)
            scanTrack(trackReader.tail, count + 1, frame2.time)
          else
            (trackReader.tail, Track(frame.trackId, count, frame.time, end))
        }

      val (scanReader2, track) = scanTrack(scanReader.tail, 1, frame.time)
      scanTracks(scanReader2, track :: acc)
    }

  scanTracks(reader, Nil)
}
```

The benefit is that the outer `scanTracks` has drastically reduced state being passed in its signature, while inner `scanTrack` doesn't have to pick up all the state that used to be in the outer, since anything that isn't changed during the inner recursion is accessible in scope.
Since the inner `scanTrack` always completes its recursion before another `scanTracks` recursion is required, `scanTracks` remains *tail-recursive* only ever calling itself as an exit condition.